# Passing a parameter to http.get in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I'm doing a http or https get request (depends on the url) and I want to pass the same callback function to both http or https get request.
my problem is that I also want to pass another parameter to the callback function.
How can I do it?

For example how can I pass myParameter to the callback function?

```
var myParameter = 1
if(url.indexOf('https') === 0 ) {
    https.get(url, callbackFunc);
else{
    http.get(url, callbackFunc);
}

function callbackFunc(res, myParameter){}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, change the parameter order of callbackFunc to

```
function callbackFunc(myParameter, res) {

}
```

(myParameter first so we can bind it as shown below, then the res)

Then you can do:

```
var boundCallback = callbackFunc.bind(null, myParameter);
```

Then use `boundCallback` instead of `callbackFunc` when you call http or https get.

Comment: Thanks, it works! the error isn't the 2nd, it's the res

Answer (score 4):

Create a function that returns the `callbackFunction`, storing your custom parameter in a closure

```
function createCallback(myParam) {
    return function(res) {
           console.log(res, myParam);
    }
}

var myParameter = 1
if(url.indexOf('https') === 0 ) {
    https.get(url, createCallback(myParameter));
else{
    http.get(url, createCallback(myParameter2));
}
```

You could just use an extra anonymous function also

```
var myParameter = 1
if(url.indexOf('https') === 0 ) {
    https.get(url, function(res){
       myCallback(res, param1);
    });
else{
    http.get(url,  function(res){
       myCallback(res, param2);
    });
}
```

Or you can use [`Function.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) as suggested by [Peter Lyons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31589398/227299). The second and subsequent arguments will be passed to your callback before the call time arguments.